# what is the meaning of "Let me get my ass up. "

Tags: meaning

Today I saw this sentence surfing on the internet.

> Let me get my ass up and head to the gym.

can you explain it with easy sentence or replacement?

Plus,
which of the followings is the most identical to "Let me get my ass up." ?

1. OMG, I should get up right now.
2. OMG, I should hurry up right now.
3. please anyone gets me up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When someone is "sitting on his/her ass", or the non-vulgar version "sitting on his/her butt", it is an idiom meaning to be lazy or unmotivated.

Related: Someone angry at someone being lazy may then ask them to "move their ass" or "move their butt", or "get your butt moving."

So ...

> Let me get my ass up and head to the gym.

This means the speaker is recognizing or acknowledging themselves as being lazy or unmotivated, but is forcing themselves to break free of the laziness or acquire the necessary motivation to proceed.

It doesn't mean to hurry.  It can imply that the person is in a comfortable state, such as tucked in bed or otherwise relaxing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this sentence is used for if someone decided to go to the gym.
People generally struggle with getting their ass to the gym, they hesitate and lazy. So I guess this is why 'Let me get my ass up', like 'let me go a(head) to the gym'. I guess.:)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added more to my question. please give a look. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

> I need to **get off my ass** and head to the gym.

It has to do with not being motivated to go to the gym.

This can also be used as a exclamation to someone:

> **Get off your ass** and go back to work!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I like yours. but i'm not native speaker so I wanted its exact meaning.  and moreover, I assume that a lot of people here are mostly native english speaker. we can find the express being used the most commonly  by googling. I can't understand why native speakers are unable to explain this. :(

Comment: 1. Where you are in the English speaking world is important, since idioms are often localized. 2. Age and lifestyle also matter.